# Cascading reveal of paragraphs in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do you to implement the following use case in AngularJS: I need a stack of paragraphs each has to be visible if the previous sibling has some specific state (eg. a field on the $scope) set.

```
<p ng-controller="genericCtrl as c1">

   <button ng-click="someExpression = true">Show next</button>
</p>

<p ng-if="c1.someExpression" ng-controller="genericCtrl as c2">

   <button ng-click="c2.someExpression = true">Show next</button>
</p>

<p ng-if="c2.someExpression" ng-controller="genericCtrl as c3">

... and so and so
</p>
```

The above code is just concept as you can not reference a sibling controller. the best was if I could avoid referencing any controllers and work with some kind of sibling stuff.

Answer (score 1):

your controller only applies to this paragraph, so your subsequent paragraphs won't work because they are outside the scope of this controller

```
<div ng-controller="genericCtrl as c1">

<p > 
   <button ng-click="someExpression = true">Show next</button>
</p>

<p ng-if="c1.someExpression" ng-controller="genericCtrl as c2">

   <button ng-click="c2.someExpression = true">Show next</button>
</p>

<p ng-if="c2.someExpression" ng-controller="genericCtrl as c3">

... and so and so
</p>

</div>
```

So you need one top level parent, and nest the other controllers within it

if you're just looking how to cascade visible paragraphs here is an example way to do it http://plnkr.co/edit/SdGZBR5khsVD9zojhQYS?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the effort so I can certainly upvote this but regrettably I can not accept. My initial problem is that I can not ng-repeate: the content to be displayed is authored from the html side. something like a declarative model.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're using paragraphs, you should switch to divs so you can nest, you can nest the items like this. http://plnkr.co/edit/kUjrzlv2PmtyxgcZfFi0?p=preview

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl"> Test - Main
  <button ng-click="c1 = true">Show Next 1</button>
  <div ng-show="c1 == true" ng-controller="secondCtrl">
    <button ng-click="c2 = true">Show Next 2</button>
    <div ng-show="c2 == true" ng-controller="thirdCtrl">
      <button ng-click="c3 = true">Show Next 3</button>
      <div ng-show="c3 == true" ng-controller="fourthCtrl">
        <button ng-click="c4 = true">Show Next 4</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way, you create child scopes and should work fine

`var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.c1 = false;
});
app.controller('secondCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.c2 = false;
});
app.controller('thirdCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.c3 = false;
});
app.controller('fourthCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.c4 = false;
});`

I believe this is exactly what you are looking for